# RichTextBox.RTF not accepting String generated from Database - C#

Tags: c#, rtf

I have a bit of a weird problem here. I'm attempting to create a form that, when making a selection from a ListBox, will poll data from a database and display it in a RichTextBox. I need the data to be in RTF for formatting purposes.

It works fine if I do something like this:

```
    private void SaveListTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DescriptionName = Convert.ToString(SaveListTest.SelectedItem);
        //CallDescriptionTest();
        CallDescriptionTest2();
        SaveRichTest.Rtf = DescriptionText;
    }

    public void CallDescriptionTest2()
    {
        switch (DescriptionName)
        {
            case "Test":
                DescriptionText = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ Test}";
                break;
            case "Words":
                DescriptionText = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ A really long phrase}";
                break;
        }
    }
```

In such a case, the RichTextBox (SaveRichTest) will take the data and display it just fine.

However, if I do something like this, where the Description column in the database has the text entered exactly as above (ex - @"{\rtf1\ansi\ Test}"):

```
    private void SaveListTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DescriptionName = Convert.ToString(SaveListTest.SelectedItem);
        CallDescriptionTest();
        //CallDescriptionTest2();
        SaveRichTest.Rtf = DescriptionText;
    }

    public void CallDescriptionTest()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(BuildDB))
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql = String.Format("Select * from Abilities where Name = '{0}'", DescriptionName);
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    DescriptionText = Convert.ToString(oReader["Description"]);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This will instead cause the program to crash, with an error that the "File format is not valid".

I know the text is pulling from the database correctly, because if I change "SaveRichTest.Rtf" to "SaveRichTest.Text", it displays it properly (albeit with the RTF formatting code displayed).

I just can't figure out why it won't take the string properly in the second case. It makes no sense to me whatsoever. Can someone help?

Comment: Just a nit: calling con.Close() is not necessary, since it gets closed when the connection is disposed.

Comment: Huh, every time I saw a tutorial, they always did a con.Close() after they were done reading from the database, so I assumed it was necessary.

Comment: It doesn't really hurt to call Close(), but wrapping the connection in a using block calls Dispose() automatically, which itself will close the connection.

Comment: C#, RTF, and SQL have different metacharacters and different ways of escaping metacharacters. For example, `@"{\rtf1\ansi\ Test}"` is a C# string; it is not an RTF string and not an SQL string. It is not clear from your question what you are actually assigning to `DescriptionText`. Please post the actual text returned by `Convert.ToString(oReader["Description"])`, not including metacharacters and not escaped for C#, SQL or anything else.

Comment: The exact entry I have in my database is this: @"{\rtf1\ansi Test}"   I'm trying to get it to display just the word Test by itself. DescriptionText is a public string, and anything else you're asking should already be in the top post. I said exactly what I'm trying to do with it. As for that text string not being an "RTF String" as you say, if it's typed into my code directly as shown above, and passed into a RichTextBox.RTF, it takes it and displays it perfect. I'm just trying to add the middleman of pulling from a database, and that's causing the issue.

Comment: As I have explained, `@"{\rtf1\ansi Test}"` is a C# string, not RTF. The RTF is `{\rtf1\ansi Test}` and if you want RTF you should store that in your database. Do not include the `@` as that is C# syntax for verbatim strings. Do not include the `"` as those are C# characters for delimiting strings.

Comment: Holy crap, that actually did it. Now, if only you hadn't posted that as an in-line reply, I could have actually marked it as the correct solution...

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the case when you tried to show your output in plain text your output was: `@"{\rtf1\ansi\ Test}`

This would mean when you want to show this string formatted directly from the database you would pass it `"@"{\rtf1\ansi\ Test}""` instead of the correct format. I'd suggest you store the format without the @ in the database and simply show the result.

Comment: I tried adding the "@" as part of the oRead process, but it didn't help any. The quotes were also intact when the string displayed as plain text, so I don't think adding a second set of quotes will help, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Changed the oread to "while (oReader.Read())
                    {
                        DescriptionText = "@" + Convert.ToString(oReader["Description"]);
                    }", as well as adding double-quotes to each entry in the database. Still no good, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh how dumb I was. You shouldn't even need the @ in the first place. It was only needed to escape the \ in your first example but won't be needed if you get the string directly from the db

Comment: Ah, fair enough. That's at least one part clarified then. Honestly, I'm really rusty on C#, since I'm picking up a project I started a little over a year ago, and haven't worked on in around seven or eight months, so I forget little things like this.